# Skew symmetric Matrix - Commutative property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

If A and B are two odd size skew symmetric matrices(for example $3 \times 3 $). Let us say $X=AB,Y=BA$

**Question**

What is the general relationship between X and Y? Can we write Y using X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$X^T=(AB)^T=B^TA^T=(-B)(-A)=BA=Y$$